# UWP/WinRT: When calling CachedFileManger::DeferUpdates, getting Access Denied on files in Dropbox folder

Tags: windows-runtime, win-universal-app, c++-cx

I've got a Universal Windows Platform app that saves files. For the most part it works perfectly. However, whenever I attempt to save a file into a folder watched by Dropbox, I'm getting this exception:

> Platform::AccessDeniedException ^ at memory location 0x045FD0D0. HRESULT:0x80070005 Access is denied.
>   WinRT information: Access is denied.

This is caused by this line in my code, called right before I save the file:

```
CachedFileManager::DeferUpdates(file);
```

Nothing in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.cachedfilemanager.deferupdates) for this call suggests to me what the problem is, or indeed that this exception could even be thrown, though of course exceptions aren't well-documented throughout most of the API.

This problem does not occur in folders watched by OneDrive.

It does not appear to matter whether or not the file is already synced to Dropbox. If the file is new, then a new file will be created and then this exception will be thrown. If the file is existing, then this exception will be thrown before it can be updated.

Why is this happening and how can I properly fix it?

Right now, I've simply enclosed the line in a try catch block where I discard `AccessDeniedException`.

Update: I just switched to Windows Insider previews. I'm on Build 14295 and this problem has slightly mutated. This is the new exception:

> Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x00000043892FB9F0. HRESULT:0x8000FFFF Catastrophic failure

Still have no idea why this is happening, but a similar hacked solution works, where now I also discard `COMException`.

Answer (score 0):

This means you don't have access to save files at that location from your Winrt code.  It is locked down pretty tight as far as file IO permissions go.  It sounds like you are not using FileSavePicker to save the file but rather you are creating the filestorage object yourself and specifying the file path location manually?

If you use FileSavePicker, it will return a stroagefile object that has all the permissions you need to save the file at whatever location the user selected.

```
                FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
                savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
                // Dropdown of file types the user can save the file as
                savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(this.loadedFile.FileType.Substring(1), new List<string>() { this.loadedFile.FileType });
                // Default extension if the user does not select a choice explicitly from the dropdown
                savePicker.DefaultFileExtension = this.loadedFile.FileType;
                // Default file name if the user does not type one in or select a file to replace
                savePicker.SuggestedFileName = file.Name.Trim();
                //savePicker.view
                StorageFile savedItem = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

                if (savedItem != null)
                {
                    CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(savedItem);
                    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(savedItem, new byte[0]); //truncate current content in case it already exists
                    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(savedItem, buffer);
                    await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(savedItem);                          
                }
```

Comment: No, this happens even with FileSavePicker. It's something special about the Dropbox folder. I can use the same code and save a file anywhere as far as I can tell, including the root folder on a drive, but it chokes on anything in the Dropbox folder.

Comment: I have an app built already that would launch the fileSavePicker and so I installed dropbox to test saving to the dropbox folder.  It works just fine for me.  Are you navigating specifically to c:\Users\[User]\Dropbox to save?  Or some other shortcut path?  Have you tried with Dropbox version 3.8.8?

Comment: Are you able to save the file to another temp location such as in the documents folder and then copy it to the storageFile object the user selected from the Dropbox folder?

Comment: Are you calling DeferUpdates? Since it is that call specifically that is causing the exception for me. My Dropbox folder is located at D:\Dropbox, and I'm navigating directly there. I just updated Dropbox to 3.8.8 and the problem still occurs. Unless I'm missing something, creating the file elsewhere and then copying it won't change anything, as the problem call is when I attempt to DeferUpdates at the destination inside of Dropbox's folder tree. This is before any of my code to actually write data to a file.

Comment: I modified my answer to include an IF block after my await PickSaveFileAsync call.  It works just fine for me and I don't get the exception.  are there any special permissions on the D:\Dropbox folder?   For me, SYSTEM, [User], and Administrators have all permissions to that particular folder: Full Control, Modify, Read & Execute, List folder contents, Read, Write

Comment: I have the same permissions. It's very strange to me that this problem arises only on the call to DeferUpdates, not to the call to actually write to file. I'm testing on Windows 10, I wonder if that could be a factor?

Comment: Alas, I am using Windows 8.1.  I'll test 10 when I get home from work tonight.

Comment: Were you ever able to test this to see if you could reproduce the issue?